# Graph Theory :: Graph Conversion

Tags: graph-theory

How can i convert edges to vertices and vice versa. I know that if two vertices share same edge than in conversion that two edges are adjacent. But i can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given graph $G$ you can build it's [line graph](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_249.html) $L(G)$. Then each edge of $G$ is a vertex of $L(G)$. However each vertex of $G$ corresponds to a clique in $L(G)$, not to an edge.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of "dual graph" idea, but it doesn't really work. Consider a triangle with vertices $X, Y, Z$ and center $C$. Connect each vertex to each other (i.e., $XY, YZ, ZY, XC, YC, ZC$ are the edges). You now want to make a graph with six edges and four vertices. Let's look near vertex $X$ of the original:

1. There are three edges coming from $X$, namely $XY, XZ, XC$. These will each be *vertices* in the new graph. I'll call them $v_{XY}, v_{XZ}, v_{XC}$.
2. The vertex $X$ itself will have to become a new *edge* (which I'll call $e_X$).

Now...what vertices will be the ends of the edge $e_X$? Clearly they need to be ... well, all *three* of $v_{XY}, v_{XZ}, v_{XC}$. But an edge has only *two* ends.

Hence the "dualizing" construction that you're hoping for is impossible.